# How can I use `str.format` directly as `__repr__`?

Tags: python, string-formatting, self, repr

Say I want to debug a simple class with an attribute `myattribute`. I create a `repr` method like this:

```
class SimpleClass:
  def __repr__(self):
    return "{0.myattribute}".format(self)
```

It feels a bit redundant, so I would prefer to use `format` directly:

```
class SimpleClass:
  __repr__ = "{0.myattribute}".format
```

...but that fails with an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I understand it that `format` cannot access the `self` argument, but I do not see why.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a CPython limitation – or what else?

Comment: You could do this `__repr__ = lambda self: "{0.myattribute}".format(self)` but I think it's worse than a `def`

Comment: note: don't do that.

Comment: My handwavy explanation is that it probably has to do with the difference between bound and unbound methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"{0.myattribute}".format` is already a bound method on the string object (`"{0.myattribute}"`). So when the calling code attempts to look up, say, `x.__repr__` (where `x` is a `SimpleClass` instance), Python finds the `__repr__` attribute of `SimpleClass`, but then cannot recognize it as a `SimpleClass` method - the descriptor protocol is not honoured (the string method has no `__get__` attribute).

It appears that in 3.4, using a `lambda` will work, although I could have sworn it had to be a real function in previous versions. `functools.partial` will not work. But you really should be using a real function anyway. Sorry it's not as DRY as you'd like.

Comment: Lambdas can do this in 2.7

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but are you sure with the `__get__` argumentation? From what I found, it is related to the `__self__` attribute. Anyway, I'll have to do some research on why is method binding designed like this.

Comment: Aha, it is really `__get__`. It is just a pity that seems not to be in the official documentation, I had to read a few blogposts.